# Decimal Multiplication Without Multiplication

Tags: recreational-mathematics

My friend has recently been challenging me to solve some maths problems, the latest challange is to find a method of finding the answer of $2.5 \cdot 2.5$ without ever using multiplication.
Now with whole numbers this is easy, you would just use repeated addition.
Example: $3 \cdot 3= 3 + 3 + 3$.
However this isn't possible with decimal numbers.(As far as I know)
Is there a way to do this and the method also working for all other decimal numbers?

Comment: If you have a finite decimal representation, you can do the same trick, just move the decimal (e.g. to perform $2.5\times2.5$ add $25$ to itself $25$ times and then shift the decimal 2 places to the left). This wouldn't work for irrational numbers though.

Comment: Alternatively, for $2.5\times 2.5$ it isn't that hard to add $2.5$ twice and then add half again (in a sense using a combination of addition and division instead of multiplication).

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt : but moving the decimal is multiplying by 10. A tongue in cheek answer : $2.5*2.5 = \exp(\ln(2.5)+\ln(2.5))$ : I don't use multiplication, just addition, logarithm and exponentiation ^^

Comment: @Tryss Well, any operation is going to end up being equivalent to multiplication... I guess the idea (as it seems to me) is that you never have to perform the standard multiplication algorithm. Heh, and that's a nice solution.

Comment: A nice exercise is to prove the following that my dad taught me when I was a kid: to mulitply by itself any number ending in five, say $\;X5\;$ , just multiply $\;X\;$ by $\;X+1\;$ and then just attach $\;25\;$ at the end right to the product. For example, $\;25\cdot25\;=(2\cdot3)25=625\;,\;\;145\cdot145=(14\cdot15)25=21025\;$ , etc. With decimal numbers the similar trick is obvious: $\;2.5\cdot2.5=6.25\;$ .